# Can I retrain OpenCV DNN face detector using my own face dataset and .pb .pbtxt files provided by OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, caffe, face-detection

I want to fine tune existing OpenCV DNN face detector to a face images database that I own. I have opencv_face_detector.pbtxt and opencv_face_detector_uint8.pb tensorflow files provided by OpenCV. I wonder if based on this files is there any way to fit the model to my data? So far, I haven't also managed to find any tensorflow training script for this model in OpenCV git repository and I only know, that given model is and SSD with resnet-10 as a backbone. I am also not sure, reading the information on the internet, if I can resume training from .pb file. Are you aware of availability of any scripts defining the model, that could be used for training? Would pbtxt and pb files be enough to continue training on new data?

Also, I noticed that there is a git containing caffe version of this model https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd. Although I never worked with caffe before, would it be possible/easier to use existing weight (caffe .pg and .pbtxt files are also available in OpenCV's github) and fit the model to my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this in opencv, but I think you'd be able to load the model into tensorflow and use [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) to retrain.

The usual advice about transfer learning applies. You'd probably want to freeze most of the early layers and only retrain the last one or two. A slow learning rate would be advised as well.